# Select specific fields from DB export that includes Json

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7, awk

I have an export from a DB table that has the following columns:

```
name|value|age|external_atributes
```

The external_atribute is on Json format. So the export looks like this:

```
George|10|30|{"label1":1,"label2":2,"label3":3,"label4":4,"label5":5,"label6":"6","label7":"7","label8":"8"}
```

Which is the most efficient way (since the export has more than 1m lines) to keep only the name and the values from `label2`, `label5` and `label6`. For example from the above export I would like to keep only:

```
George|2|5|6
```

Edit: I am not sure for the sequence of the fields/variables on the JSON part. Data could be also for example:

```
George|10|30|{"label2":2,"label1":1,"label4":4,"label3":3,"label6":6,"label8":"8","label7":"7","label5":"5"}
```

Also the fact that some of the values are double quoted, while some are not, is intentional (This is how they appear also on the export).

My understanding until now is that I have to use something that has a JSON parser like Python or jq.

This is what i created on Python and seems that is working as expected:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys,json
with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as file:
for line in file:
            fields = line.split('|')
               print (fields[0], json.loads(fields[3])['label2'], json.loads(fields[3])['label5'], json.loads(fields[3])['label6'], sep='|')
```

output:

```
George|2|5|6
```

Since I am looking for the most efficient way to do this, any comment is more than welcome.

Comment: On SO we do encourage people to add their efforts in their post, kindly do so and let us know then.

Comment: Please, give more details. Is the one presented the most general format? Is the fact that some of the values are double quoted, while some are not, intentional? If you do not provide this context, most answers will be poor and less likely useful to other users.

Comment: @PavlosMaragkos, based on your update my understanding is that the script you are looking for must take some kind of inputs besides the text file itself. In your example these inputs are the three labels used to extract values from within the braced (`{}`) expression (hence the question: _do you always request exactly 3 labels?_), and the index of the the `name` in the `|`-separated list (hence the question: _is `name` always the first one in the list?_)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if the data are easy to parse, I advise to use a json parser like `jq` to extract your json data:

```
<file jq -rR '
   split("|")|[ .[0], (.[3]|fromjson|(.label2,.label5,.label6)|tostring)]|join("|")'
```

Both options `-R` and `-r` allows jq to accept and display a string as input and output (instead of json data).

The `split` function enable getting all fields into an array that can be indexed with number `.[0]` and `.[3]`.

The third field is then parsed as json data with the function `fromjson` such that the wanted labels are extracted.

All wanted fields are put into an array and `join` together with the `|` delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

You could split with multiple delimiters using a character class.
The following prints the desired result:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = "[|,:]";OFS="|"} {gsub(/"/,"",$15)}{print $1,$7,$13,$15}'
```

The above solution assumes that the input data is structured.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is about record-based text edits, `awk` is most probably the best tool to accomplish the task. However, here it is a `sed` solution:

```
sed 's/\([^|]*\).*label2[^0-9]*\([0-9]*\).*label5[^0-9]*\([0-9]*\).*label6[^0-9]*\([0-9]*\).*/\1|\2|\3|\4/' inputFile
```